# Custom Meta Box Causing Error: "Are you sure you want to do this? Please try again."

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, errors, publish

My custom post type have a meta box that is listing another custom post types in its meta box. And it is causing error each time I try to publish a post with that custom post type.
It is always bring to a page that say "Are You Sure You Want To Do This? Please Try Again".
It does not have any problem in my localhost, but does not work when I run it on my web hosting.

Here is the codes:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'ind_pricing_tables_boxes' );

function ind_pricing_tables_boxes() {
    $screens = array( 'indtable' );
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
    add_meta_box('indtable_boxid', __( 'Pricing Table', 'pricing_table' ), 'ind_pricing_tables_boxes_form', $screen );
    }
}

function ind_pricing_tables_boxes_form() {
    global $post;
        wp_nonce_field( 'ind_pricing_table_box_nonce' );
    $ind_table_packs = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_ind_meta_table_keypacks", true);
    $ind_table_packs = ($ind_table_packs == '') ? array() : json_decode($ind_table_packs);

    $query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'indpackage',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'order' => 'ASC'
                    )
    );

    $ind_form_box  = '<table class="form-table" border="1">';
    $ind_form_box  .= "<tr><th style=''>
                    <b>Select Package</b>
              </th>
              <td>
                    <b>Package Names</b>
              </td></tr>";

    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        $checked_whichs = (in_array($query->post->ID, $ind_table_packs)) ? "checked" : "";
        $ind_form_box  .= "<tr><th style=''>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='pricing_ind_table_packages[]' $checked_whichs value='" . $query->post->ID . "' />
              </th><td>" . $query->post->post_title . " </td></tr>";

    endwhile;

    $ind_form_box  .= '</table>';

    echo $ind_form_box ;
}
```

What causing the error?

**Save metabox function**

```
function ind_save_pricing_boxtables($post_id) {

    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['ind_pricing_table_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if ('indtable' == $_POST['post_type'] && current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {

        $pricing_ind_table_packages = (isset($_POST['pricing_ind_table_packages']) ? $_POST['pricing_ind_table_packages'] : array());
        $pricing_ind_table_packages = json_encode($pricing_ind_table_packages);

        update_post_meta($post_id, "_ind_meta_table_keypacks", $pricing_ind_table_packages);
    } else {
        return $post_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think the problem is in your nonce, can you post save metabox function code here to investigate the problem.

Comment: Yes! I also noticed about it after I researched the problem. And it seem the save metabox function won't be nonced. Updated the question with the save function.

Answer (score 2):

so you need to correct your nonce field add a second pram nonce name, more information on WordPress codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field)

```
// wp nonce field
wp_nonce_field( $action, $name, $referer, $echo );

// replace yours with below
wp_nonce_field( 'ind_pricing_table_box_nonce', 'ind_pricing_nonce' );
```

now verify your nonce, more info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce)

```
wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, $action );

// replace yours with below
if (!wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['ind_pricing_nonce'], 'ind_pricing_table_box_nonce' )) {
    return $post_id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But as I said before, it seem the meta box can't be nonced. I received this message **Notice: Undefined index: ind_pricing_nonce in /home4/myusername/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/ind_css3_pricing_table/ind_css3_pricing_table_grid.php on line 445**

Comment: echo your nonce field `echo wp_nonce_field( 'ind_pricing_table_box_nonce', 'ind_pricing_nonce' );` or `wp_nonce_field( 'ind_pricing_table_box_nonce', 'ind_pricing_nonce', '', true );`

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but it is still showing the notice above.

Comment: can you show me code on line 445

Comment: It is the first line of this wp verify nonce: 
if (!wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['ind_pricing_nonce'], 'ind_pricing_table_box_nonce' )) {
    return $post_id;'
}